# jQuery clock not working in jsf 1.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-1.2, timepicker

I am implementing jQuery clock in my application. This clock is working fine in HTML/JSP page but not working in jsf 1.2.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<f:view>
      <f:verbatim>
    <html>

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>JSF</title >
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="WEB-INF/clock/include/ui-1.10.0/ui-       lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/clock/include/jquery-1.9.0.min.js/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="WEB-INF/clock/include/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js/"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="WEB-INF/clock/include/ui-1.10.0/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" type="text/css" />


   <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/clock/include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/clock/include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/clock/include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/clock/include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/clock/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#timepicker_showon').timepicker({
                    showOn: 'button',
                    button: $('.timepicker_button_trigger'),
                    showLeadingZero: false,
                    timeSeparator: ':'
                });

            });

  </script>

        </head>
        </f:verbatim>
        <h:form id="clock">
        <body>
            <h1><h:outputText value="JavaServer Faces"/></h1>

            <f:verbatim>  <label for="timepicker_showon">Select Time</label></f:verbatim>
            <h:inputText  style="width: 70px;" id="timepicker_showon" value="00:00" />
            <f:verbatim>      <div class='timepicker_button_trigger'
             style="width: 16px; height:16px; 
                    display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #222222; margin-top: 3px; cursor:pointer"></div>

            </f:verbatim>

        </body>
        </h:form>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

I have read that `$` is not defined. I have tried alternatives like:

```
       $ = jQuery
       $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

But these solutions are also not working.

I have requirements to implement the clock, and I have already used Tomahawks calender to select a date, so I need to implement a different timepicker. Please suggest any other alternatives (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the generated IDs for your component on HTML. The `<h:form>` ID will be automatically appended to the IDs of the inner components, so

```
<h:form id="clock">
    <h:inputText id="timepicker_showon" />
</h:form>
```

Will generate this HTML:

```
<form id="clock">
    <input type="text" id="clock:timepicker_showon" />
</form>
```

You have two ways to solve this:

1. Pass the right client ID to your jQuery functions:

   ```
   $('#clock\\:timepicker_showon')
   ```

   Note that you must use `\\:` because `:` is reserver for jQuery selector (more info [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-get-jsf-id-via-jquery/)).
2. Use `prependId="false"` in your `<h:form>` so the inner components IDs won't have the form ID:

   ```
   <h:form id="clock" prependId="false">
       <h:inputText id="timepicker_showon" />
   </h:form>
   ```

   This will generate this HTML:

   ```
   <form id="clock">
       <input type="text" id="timepicker_showon" />
   </form>
   ```

An additional note: In your profile you say *I want to learn jsf.*, if you're learning in your own way, then it would be better to study JSF 2.

Comment: I have already tried what u are saying...please suggest any timepicker with good UI that is tested with jsf 1.2....Thanks

Comment: @rishi use the [RichFaces v3.3 Calendar component](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf?c=calendar&tab=usage). Don't use RichFaces 4 since it is for JSF 2.x

Comment: could you please tell me any jquery timepicker which you have used with jsf 1.2.

Comment: @rishi I needed none because RichFaces 3.3 already ships jquery and has JSF based components. No need to do jquery things on my own. I follow the rule of not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Seem like you've included jQuery three times:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/clock/include/jquery-1.9.0.min.js/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="WEB-INF/clock/include/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js/"></script>
```

The second `<script>` tag also missing closing `</script>`. Try to keep one link only and see how.

Comment: I have tried what u said..But its not working. I think that the problem is something else.

Comment: @rishi Sorry but I never experienced with `jsf` before so hope that someone else can help you in this case :)

Comment: Yes, this is a JSF problem with ID's of components inside `<h:form>`. Very JSF specific.